# GCM app not receiving messages

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm developing my first Android app. I've searched throughly but still can't get to a solution and I no longer have much time before the finish line.

My app can register to GCM servers. My server isn't yet ready but I do test message sending (server->device) hurling them through an online service (note, GCM returns success upon those sendings). The problem is that it seems no messages arrive from the GooglePlay service to my receiver.

Starting from the Android Developer guide, I setup those pieces of code:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="it.uniroma1.informatica.didapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="it.uniroma1.informatica.didapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <receiver
        android:name="it.uniroma1.informatica.didapp.remote.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="it.uniroma1.informatica.didapp" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="it.uniroma1.informatica.didapp.remote.GCMIntentService" />
```

GCMBroadcastReceiver.java

```
public class GCMBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), GCMIntentService.class.getName());
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}
```

}

and, finally, GCMIntentService.java

```
public class GCMIntentService extends IntentService {
public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

public GCMIntentService() {
    super("GCMIntentService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

    if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
               if(GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
        } else if(GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " + extras.toString());
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Message: " + extras.toString());
        }
    }
    GCMBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}

private void sendNotification(String msg) {
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, Start.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
        .bigText(msg))
        .setContentText(msg);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
}
```

All I need is very simple:

1. Server send notification (without payload) to GCM
2. GCM forwards it to device(s)
3. Device show a notification in the system bar and eventually start an activity

Answer (score 0):

I believe this may be the problem :

`ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), GCMIntentService.class.getName());`

`context.getPackageName()` returns `it.uniroma1.informatica.didapp`, but your intent service is located in `it.uniroma1.informatica.didapp.remote`. Try moving it to the main package of the app.

> **public ComponentName (String pkg, String cls)**
>
> Added in API level 1
>
> Create a new component identifier.
>
> Parameters
>
> **pkg**    The name of the package that the component exists in. Can not be null.
>
> **cls**    The name of the class inside of pkg that implements the component. Can not be null.

Comment: I tried to both move the class inside the main package and to replace the arguments of the ComponentName constructor, but the problem persists :(

Comment: @OliverTran Is `onReceive` ever called? Perhaps you should run the app in a debugger and put a break point inside that method.